# Correct steps after in-app purchase is successful

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I tried the following code for in-app purchase. I'm using `CurrentAppSimulator` for testing purpose.

```
private async void history_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool OK = true;

    // Get the license info
    // The next line is commented out for testing.
    // licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;

    // The next line is commented out for production/release.       
    LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
    if (!licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["PremiumFeatures"].IsActive)
    {
        try
        {
            // The customer doesn't own this feature, so 
            // show the purchase dialog.

            await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("PremiumFeatures", false);
            // the in-app purchase was successful
            OK = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // The in-app purchase was not completed because 
            // an error occurred.
            OK = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // The customer already owns this feature.
        OK = true;
    }

    if (OK)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(HistoryPage));
    }
}
```

However, the dialog keep pop up, every time I perform `history_Click`, even I choose S_OK. I expect `licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["PremiumFeatures"].IsActive` should changed to true, after I buy the `PremiumFeatures`.

[image]

I guess, perhaps when the in-app purchase was successful, I need to turn on `IsActive` flag, so that it will not show me purchase dialog again.

```
        // the in-app purchase was successful
        OK = true;
        // Compile error!!!
        licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["PremiumFeatures"].IsActive = true;
```

OK. Seems like `IsActive` is a read only field. So, may I know, **what is the correct way to handle purchase successful case?**

### Update :

After looking at [Trial app and in-app purchase sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a/view/SourceCode), I realize having the following code can have `IsActive` changed from `false` to `true` **automatically**, after purchasing successful. **(But why it works?)**

```
    private async Task LoadInAppPurchaseProxyFileAsync()
    {
        StorageFolder proxyDataFolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("data");
        StorageFile proxyFile = await proxyDataFolder.GetFileAsync("in-app-purchase.xml");
        licenseChangeHandler = new LicenseChangedEventHandler(InAppPurchaseRefreshScenario);
        CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation.LicenseChanged += licenseChangeHandler;
        await CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync(proxyFile);

        // setup application upsell message
        ListingInformation listing = await CurrentAppSimulator.LoadListingInformationAsync();
        var product1 = listing.ProductListings["product1"];
        var product2 = listing.ProductListings["product2"];
        Product1SellMessage.Text = "You can buy " + product1.Name + " for: " + product1.FormattedPrice + ".";
        Product2SellMessage.Text = "You can buy " + product2.Name + " for: " + product2.FormattedPrice + ".";
    }
```

However, the "Is already bought" status **is not persistence**. If I close the app and start it again, it will thought my "Premium Feature" to "is not bought yet".

**How am I suppose the make this behavior persistence?**

Comment: I think you are correct, the IsActive flag is read from some external XML when using the Simulator. In the real version IsActive will be automatically set.

Comment: Dude you all are getting it wrong. Ur dealing with an xml from the storage folders so don't expect it to some kind on buying trial.

just fetches the price from an xml ... I have no idea y u people are voting down my answer :)

Comment: You all wont get any other proper answer for this... mine one is up in the windows store and working :) now keep searching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it's not automatically updated when you click OK. It only returns the correct status like it should do in the Windows Store.

What I think is an option to do, but I haven't implemented it myself is to use `ReloadSimulatorAsync(proxyFile)` method. Before you call this method you have to update the in-app-purchase.xml yourself save it and pass the file to the ReloadSimulatorAsync method.

Personally I would use the manual update of the xml file. But I can't Judge about that for your application / application flow.

A good start for automating this process is the sample "In-app purchase" app which you can find [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a/view/SourceCode). If you look in the code file InAppPurchase.xaml.cs you will see already a bit of code for your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your example link. Not solving my problem, but I have some new finding. I updated my question.

Answer (score 8):

PLEASE READ

I would assume, based on your experience, that App.IsTrial is set to true. You cannot commit a purchase while the app is in trial mode or (for any other reason) is not active. Please note that I am referring to the App and not the feature/product. Once the app is active your purchase will succeed.

Comment: Wow, that would be a bunch!

Comment: This was very close to my solution. I had both `IsActive` and `IsTrial` set to false in my `WindowsStoreProxy.xml`. I needed to set `IsActive` to true, then the state was updated correctly after a simulated purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna clear this out. When executing

```
  try {

        await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("PremiumFeatures", false);
        OK = true

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        OK = false;
    }
```

OK will not only be true if the user bought the feature, it will also be true if he cancels the buy or he cant be identified or he disables his network connection. So this is the wrong way to check if the purchase was successfull. Basically Anobik was right, you have to check afterwards if the license is purchased so the right code would be:

```
if (!licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["PremiumFeatures"].IsActive)
{
    try
    {
        // The customer doesn't own this feature, so 
        // show the purchase dialog.

        await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("PremiumFeatures", false);
                if (licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["PremiumFeatures"].IsActive)
                {
                    // the in-app purchase was successful
                     OK = true;
                    //Success in purchase use ur own code block
                }
                else
                {
                     OK = false;
                    //error in purchase use your own code block
                }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // The in-app purchase was not completed because 
        // an error occurred.
        OK = false;
    }
}
else
{
    // The customer already owns this feature.
    OK = true;
}

if (OK)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(HistoryPage));
}
```

But still, if you compile you will see that it doesn't work. I think, this is because the CurrentAppSimulator will not make a permanent change to the license.
I hope this is true :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to check if the license `IsActive` immediately after the purchase. Instead, you can (you'd better) store the result of `RequestProductPurchaseAsync`, which is of type `PurchaseResults` and has a `Status` property.  The latter in its turn is a `ProductPurchaseStatus` enum value, and if it is `Succeeded`, you can proceed without checking the license.

Answer (score -1):

You are only missing one if else condition to handle the in app purchase

Here's the code

```
private async void history_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
bool OK = true;

// Get the license info
// The next line is commented out for testing.
// licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;

// The next line is commented out for production/release.       
LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
if (!licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["PremiumFeatures"].IsActive)
{
    try
    {
        // The customer doesn't own this feature, so 
        // show the purchase dialog.

        await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("PremiumFeatures", false);
                if (licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["PremiumFeatures"].IsActive)
                {
                    // the in-app purchase was successful
                     OK = true;
                    //Success in purchase use ur own code block
                }
                else
                {
                     OK = false;
                    //error in purchase use your own code block
                }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // The in-app purchase was not completed because 
        // an error occurred.
        OK = false;
    }
}
else
{
    // The customer already owns this feature.
    OK = true;
}

if (OK)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(HistoryPage));
}
```

}

Comment: i have added the code that I meant ... please chek it again .. he has written if (!licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["PremiumFeatures"].IsActive)

which checks if it is Inactive then it enters the block - if block . 

the next if is to check wether there's no exception while purchase i mean it has been activated for the used.

Please check the link that u have provided and go through the steps in the In-app purchase section in the demo .. Ull be better clear that way :)

Comment: Who so ever down votes please research and down vote cause if I am wrong then Ill also need a correct answer. I cannot go ahead with a wrong answer :(

Comment: That still doesn't work, OK is an local variable. The next time he clicks on the button it will run the same flow as the time before. The questioner is looking for a way to make the licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["PremiumFeatures"].IsActive become true after he clicks the button and chooses OK.

Comment: :( yes because the app in the window 8 store is in a trial version it will always be active inside the if block active and it will show u have purchased. only way is to run it in currentapp not in simulator to check the prices of the products that have been uploaded to windows store for inapp purchase.

Comment: Ill explain after some time :-) its related to everything in the windows store uploading the app for verification and adding in app purchases at the time of upload ..... selecting an rbitary product name "PremiumFeatures" wont help in a purchase it will be considered as a free version and wont show any price for purchase.